# Is it possible to change vuex store from browser?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I am using vue.js and vuex.

I am storing if user has shared the product on facebook and if yes, let him buy it on a lower price than original. I am storing if he has shared or not on my database and prices are also stored on my db.

When user accesses any of the main pages, i make an api call and load that information in store. Then on checkout page i check that information in vuex store. As i dont want user to go to my vuex store and change that information directly because he would buy the product with a low price without sharing.

Is it possible to change store data from browser or any other ways other than my code ?

Comment: No, there is no way to do that unless you expose it to global object.

Comment: Are you sure? Some people say it is possible

Comment: What did they say?

Comment: I saw this : document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].__vue__.$store.state and what if i change it now?

Comment: The easiest way to know is to test it. I tested it on my own app, and yes, it can be changed by external code.

Comment: Yes it's possible. Trivial even. A user need only install the vue_devtools browser extension.

Comment: @stephen thomas, well, if production flag is turned on it suddenly becomes less trivial, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I find it unethical.

Hopefully if your information isn't validated by the back-end, there's no way ensuring if some piece of data on front-end is not manipulated. So simply - user can always fake it. However, most of the users will never open devTools and therefore will not know how to manipulate it.

Appendix: when encounter such swindling I usually just share the post with visibility restricted to myself only. So far it have always worked. So, even if one shares it, is it really shared?

Wish you success